# Costs of canceling repair?

Tags: iphone, repair, apple-store, applecare

After cracking my iPhone, I contacted apple support, started a service request, and filled out the ""Send in for Service" option. However, I am now trying to cancel (which apparently is done by simply not sending the package), but I need to know if there are any costs from a cancelled request.

iPhone 5s, iOS 8.4

Answer (score 1):

Contact Apple Support (In USA & Canada its 1-800-MY-APPLE or go to [support.apple.com](http://support.apple.com)) and let them know that you change your mind. Just make sure ask if you do receive the packaging, did they want you to send it back.

Answer (score 0):

Call 1-800-APL-CARE and give them your case number. If you have a specific repair quote and phone number to call, you could try that as well.

Cost depends on if they have done the repair and/or can reverse what they did in my experience.

Comment: I apologize if I was not clear: I have not sent the phone in, and was wondering whether there were any charges from getting the box itself that one is supposed to send the phone in.

Comment: Also, why did you delete my other question? It was related.

Comment: Again - You might be on the hook for the service fee. What did they quote you for the repair? Apple breaks things down quite clearly if you arranged service with them directly. If you don't have a quote, you might not owe anything and they'll either say keep the box or send it back.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Apple typically doesn't charge for cancelled repairs or returns however you should check your local area by contacting Apple Support.

[You can find your local Apple Support number here.](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201232)